# Amazon RDS instance recovery during mysqldump

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds, mariadb-10.3

I have a `db.t2.small` read replica, which crashes every time I run `mysqldump`.

The issues started after I made some table changes - my main suspicion is the use of `InnoDB`.

---

This replica is used as a backup (incase the main server was to fail); and allowed me to run `mysqldump` every night, so I can create an off-site backup without effecting the main server.

AWS now goes though the recovery process when I use `mysqldump`.

```
01:53:13 - Recovery of the DB instance has started. Recovery time will vary with the amount of data to be recovered.
01:57:11 - DB instance restarted
01:57:36 - Recovery of the DB instance is complete.
```

Annoying the error logs are pretty much empty, so I have no idea what's causing it to fail.

The largest tables are:

```
788 MB = report_data
410 MB = report_data_log
418 MB = email_log_boy
```

The `report_data` table used to contain 36 TEXT fields (an example of more fields being added over time), and used `MyISAM`.

I changed this to use a simpler 1 TEXT field per row (an report_id, field_name, field_value, created_date, author_id), and it's now setup to use `InnoDB`.

The overall table size has decreased a bit.

The `report_data_log` table is basically the same table structure, but with a date to record when each value was replaced (as in, on editing, the record is copied from the `report_data` table, so I have a history of what's changed in the last 3 months).

I export each table individually with:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/backup/database.cnf --skip-extended-insert --skip-dump-date db report_data_log
```

I have tried adding `--single-transaction`, but that hasn't changed anything.

The config file just contains the `username`, `password`, `host`, `ssl-ca`, and sets `ssl-verify-server-cert` to true.

The `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf` file contains:

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
```

The server configuration hasn't been changed recently, where it includes:

```
max_allowed_packet: 1073741824
net_read_timeout: 3600
net_write_timeout: 3600
```

Oddly, it's able to export the 788MB `report_data` table, but crashes after exporting ~200MB of the 410MB `report_data_log` table.

Using `db.t2.medium` will probably fix this issue, but it doubles the cost - which seems a little silly considering the main server is fine, and both are idle most of the time (never appears to exceed 25% CPU, average 1.5%; or running low on Freeable Memory).

I'm tempted to switch back to `MyISAM`, but was wondering if there are any better AWS RDS logs to find out what's happened, or if there is something different about `InnoDB` that I'm missing?

---

As an interesting aside, the "db.t2.small" MariaDB instance provides 2GB of RAM.

The parameter group sets "innodb_buffer_pool_size" to "{DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}".

But when I run:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "innodb_buffer_pool_size";
```

It returns 2147483648... so it's being set to 2GB, not 1.5GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug with Amazon RDS.

---

**Reply from Amazon on the 6th Jan 2020:**

"Starting with MariaDB 10.2.2 resizing the buffer pool is performed in chunks determined by the size of the innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size variable. Hence the buffer pool size must be a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances, since innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 1.5 GB the behavior is to round off to 1GB as the "innodb_buffer_pool_instances" is set to 8."

---

**Original Answer:**

On the "db.t2.small" MariaDB instance, it has 2GB of RAM, but `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is being incorrectly set to 2GB.

This means MariaDB **will crash** when the InnoDB buffer pool fills with too much data.

The temporary solution is to change the Parameter Group so:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
```

If you want to get an ETA from Amazon, ask them to check Case **6411919871**, from the 5th September 2019.

I did have to eventually pay them $29 to raise a "Technical" bug report, the original report was raised in August, both with Accounts, and on their Forum:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=913625